# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Internal.initializeInstanceForTests() When creating a Mock Server on Android

Tags: java, android, mocking, okhttp

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Internal.initializeInstanceForTests() When creating a Mock Server on Android`

I tried to update the dependency but it did not work.

I am new to Android Unit testing and I want to test if the API call is successful or not. I am working on the Open Source Project on https://github.com/commons-app/apps-android-commons (leaderboard branch)

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.internal.Internal.initializeInstanceForTests()V

    at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer.<clinit>(MockWebServer.java:103)
    at fr.free.nrw.commons.leaderboard.LeaderboardApiTest.initTest(LeaderboardApiTest.java:35)
```

```
public class LeaderboardApiTest {

    MockWebServer server;

    @Before
    public void initTest() {
        server = new MockWebServer();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws IOException {
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setBody("{\n"
            + "    \"status\": 200,\n"
            + "    \"username\": \"user\",\n"
            + "    \"category_count\": 0,\n"
            + "    \"limit\": null,\n"
            + "    \"avatar\": \"avatar\",\n"
            + "    \"offset\": null,\n"
            + "    \"duration\": \"all_time\",\n"
            + "    \"leaderboard_list\": [\n"
            + "        {\n"
            + "            \"username\": \"user\",\n"
            + "            \"category_count\": 0,\n"
            + "            \"avatar\": \"avatar\",\n"
            + "            \"rank\": 1\n"
            + "        }\n"
            + "    ],\n"
            + "    \"category\": \"used\",\n"
            + "    \"rank\": 1\n"
            + "}"));
        server.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void apiTest() throws IOException, JSONException {
        HttpUrl httpUrl = HttpUrl.parse(NetworkingModule.TEST_TOOLS_FORGE_URL);
        LeaderboardResponse response = sendRequest(new OkHttpClient(), httpUrl);
        Assert.assertEquals("avatar", response.getAvatar());
        Assert.assertEquals("username", response.getUsername());
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), response.getRank());
        Assert.assertEquals(Integer.valueOf(0), response.getCategoryCount());
    }

    private LeaderboardResponse sendRequest(OkHttpClient okHttpClient, HttpUrl httpUrl)
        throws IOException, JSONException {
        Request request = new Builder().url(httpUrl).build();
        Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            return gson.fromJson(response.body().toString(), LeaderboardResponse.class);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @After
    public void shutdown() throws IOException {
        server.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: This could be issue if you happen to use proguard

Comment: Could you post some of the code?

Comment: Stacktrace? Also confirm your OkHttp and MockWebServer versions match!

Comment: I have updated my question with code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating the Okhttp version fixed the problem

```
configurations.all {
        exclude module: 'okhttp-ws'
}

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.8.0"
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:4.8.0'
```

Comment: Ditto: upgraded Spring to latest 2.x version and immediately got this. Then upgraded from 3.14 to 4.10 and presto, everything worked